# Change font for a particular row in System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

For various reasons I'm using the obsolete System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid instead of DataGridView, and I need to make a particular row bold, while the others remain unbolded.

Both the row header text and the cells should be bold. I assume this is done by changing the font somehow. The only properties I found were Font and HeaderFont but they change the font for the entire control.

Comment: Maybe there is an option to do the entire painting of the cell yourself? Or to put another control into the cell(s)?

Comment: @GeorgBisseling Yes, there is. by creating a custom `DataGridColumnStyle`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new [DataGridColumnStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridcolumnstyle?view=netframework-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) and override its `Paint` methods and apply your custom paint logic to customize painting of cell. You can derive from [DataGridTextBoxColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridtextboxcolumn?view=netframework-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) and override this overload of [`Paint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridtextboxcolumn.paint?view=netframework-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#System_Windows_Forms_DataGridTextBoxColumn_Paint_System_Drawing_Graphics_System_Drawing_Rectangle_System_Windows_Forms_CurrencyManager_System_Int32_System_Drawing_Brush_System_Drawing_Brush_System_Boolean_).

You can use `rowNum` parameter which contains the row number which you are painting. Also you can extract the value of cell using `source` parameter use it to decide how render the cell.

```
public class MyDataGridTextBoxColumn : DataGridTextBoxColumn
{
    protected override void Paint(Graphics g, Rectangle bounds, CurrencyManager source,
       int rowNum, Brush backBrush, Brush foreBrush, bool alignToRight)
    {
        if (rowNum == 1) /*Specific row index*/
        {
            var value = this.PropertyDescriptor.GetValue(source.List[rowNum]);
            var text = string.Format("{0}", value);
            Rectangle rect = bounds;
            using (var format = new StringFormat())
            {
                if (alignToRight)
                    format.FormatFlags |= StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft;
                format.Alignment = (this.Alignment == HorizontalAlignment.Left) ?
                    StringAlignment.Near :
                    ((this.Alignment == HorizontalAlignment.Center) ?
                    StringAlignment.Center : StringAlignment.Far);
                format.FormatFlags |= StringFormatFlags.NoWrap;
                g.FillRectangle(backBrush, rect);
                rect.Offset(0, 2);
                rect.Height -= 2;
                var font = new Font(this.DataGridTableStyle.DataGrid.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
                g.DrawString(text, font, foreBrush, rect, format);
            }
        }
        else
            base.Paint(g, bounds, source, rowNum, backBrush, foreBrush, alignToRight);
    }
}
```

And here is the usage:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("A");
dt.Columns.Add("B");
dt.Rows.Add("1", "11");
dt.Rows.Add("2", "22");
dt.Rows.Add("3", "33");

var dg = new DataGrid();
dg.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
var ts = new DataGridTableStyle();
ts.GridColumnStyles.Add(new MyDataGridTextBoxColumn() 
    { MappingName = "A", HeaderText = "A" });
ts.GridColumnStyles.Add(new MyDataGridTextBoxColumn() 
    { MappingName = "B", HeaderText = "B" });
dg.TableStyles.Add(ts);

this.Controls.Add(dg);
dg.DataSource = dt;
dg.BringToFront();
```

Comment: By the way, surely you've thought about it, but I also recommend you to concentrate your efforts of replacing the `DataGrid` with `DataGridView`.

Comment: I'm using a custom control inheriting from DataGrid. Replacing it will be hard.

Comment: Surely you know the requirement and the situation better, but I guess you can implement / or you would have the custom control functionalities in `DataGridView`.